Is there a way to allow connections to pass over/through hidden objects?
I am using components and hidden links to force components into a grid spacing with:
    @startuml

    A1 -r[hidden]- A2 
    A2 -r[hidden]- A3
    B1 -r[hidden]- B2 
    B2 -r[hidden]- B3
    C1 -r[hidden]- C2
    C2 -r[hidden]- C3
    A1 -d[hidden]- B1
    B1 -d[hidden]- C1
    A2 -d[hidden]- B2
    B2 -d[hidden]- C2
    A3 -d[hidden]- B3
    B3 -d[hidden]- C3

    @enduml

I allocate certain components to the grid dynamically and then make the actual links and hide the grid locations I did not use.
    @startuml

    A1 -r[hidden]- A2 
    A2 -r[hidden]- A3
    B1 -r[hidden]- B2 
    B2 -r[hidden]- B3
    C1 -r[hidden]- C2
    C2 -r[hidden]- C3
    A1 -d[hidden]- B1
    B1 -d[hidden]- C1
    A2 -d[hidden]- B2
    B2 -d[hidden]- C2
    A3 -d[hidden]- B3
    B3 -d[hidden]- C3

    Hide B2
    A2 -d[norank]- C2

    @enduml

Grid with hidden component and link jumping over
When doing the above, the link between A2 and C2 does not go straight, but rather loops around. Is there a command that allows links to pass over/under/behind hidden components. So the grids structure is maintained, but the links ignore the components.
Expected results. Hidden component is removed to show how link should be

Hello! Your question is unclear. Can you include the entire plantuml source of what you're trying? You can edit your question to do that.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@fuhrmanator updated with code, current and expected results. Hope it helps

My answer follows the same strategy of using hidden lines to force a layout. However, it's important not to use the hidden class, if you want a line to go through it. GraphViz (the underlying layout algorithm) will avoid classes, even if they're not visible:
@startuml
skinparam style strictuml
hide empty members

class A1
class A2
class A3
A1 -right[hidden]- A2
A2 -right[hidden]- A3

class B1
class B3
A1 -down[hidden]- B1
A3 -down[hidden]- B3

class C1
class C2
class C3
B1 -down[hidden]- C1
C1 -right[hidden]- C2
C2 -right[hidden]- C3

A2 -- C2

@enduml

I don't think there's a general solution when using hidden lines to force layouts with arbitrary class diagrams. PlantUML is a compromise to allow quick diagram generation. If you need to control the layout fully, it's not the best tool.
Click the image to go to PlantUML's source editor online:

Edit: Using a line type of ortho might be acceptable for your first attempt:
@startuml
skinparam linetype ortho
A1 -r[hidden]- A2 
A2 -r[hidden]- A3
B1 -r[hidden]- B2 
B2 -r[hidden]- B3
C1 -r[hidden]- C2
C2 -r[hidden]- C3
A1 -d[hidden]- B1
B1 -d[hidden]- C1
A2 -d[hidden]- B2
B2 -d[hidden]- C2
A3 -d[hidden]- B3
B3 -d[hidden]- C3

Hide B2
A2 -d[norank]- C2

@enduml



Sorry my example was greatly simplified.
My grid is dynamically generated depending on an input file to force the location. At the moment the grid locations are rectangles. The rectangle alias is either:
The grid location if the input file does not have an entry or
a unique key.
the grid locations that have an key gets hidden. if I remove them then i lose my grid structure and the diagram placement gets messy.
Based on another input file links are made between the keys.

Doing this there are many links that try and squeeze through the gap between the hidden locations where it could go straight between the to and from cell if it could pass through/over/under the hidden one.
sorry I cant share more than the test in the original question.

Some people have managed to pass edges over nodes with GraphViz. https://forum.graphviz.org/t/force-straight-edges-above-through-a-node/741 Since you're generating the diagram from a program, maybe GraphViz is a better alternative (it doesn't know UML, however). I don't think it's possible in PlantUML to do this.
